# Oracle Triggers

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Requirement: Table 1 is updated using ETL tool, after that i need to truncate and insert data into table 2 using a view which is based on Table 1. What is the better, more efficient way of doing this? (without ETL tool)

What i have done so far:

I have created a trigger which is used to truncate and insert into another table "Table 2" using a view which based on the  "Table1"

Below is the code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER My_Trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON Table1 
    DECLARE PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN
    execute immediate 'truncate table Table2';COMMIT;
    insert into Table2( X,Y,Z)
    select * from MY_VIEW;
    COMMIT;
    END;
```

Now the problem is there are multiple inserts in table1 but the trigger fires after the first insert is completed. I tried using for each row but the number of inserts are more than 70k so it is very time consuming.

Please suggest a way i can perform the above job.

Comment: Are all inserts done in one transaction? If so, you can create a dbms_job in the trigger -- without an autonomous transaction and without a commit, relying on the calling environment to commit the transaction which will also cause the job to start.

Comment: never used dbms_job in the trigger, if possible can you give an example

Comment: The `truncate` will commit anyway since it's DDL, so the first one is redundant.

Comment: I don't think triggers are going to help you here. You need some way to detect that the ETL tool has finished its inserts, at which point you run your truncate/insert process. Perhaps look at what process is running the ETL process now, and see if you can add a step to automatically run after it completes?

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you should do with a trigger. Truncate table2 before you insert into table1 is a much better design.

Do not think you need that but you might want to have a look at dbms_scheduler which is a package that provides a set of procedures that allow you to run PL/SQL procedures in a certain sequence.

If you really want to go with the after statement trigger you can create another table which you use to mark that the table has already been truncated for today.

Comment: Hi Hol,

So what is the best way to do this requirements:

After Table 1 is updated i need to truncate and insert data into table 2 using a view which is based on Table 1.

Is their a better, more efficient way of doing this?